# attach .bak file of database in server or .mdf and .ldf files with Asp.net MVC project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I create a web project with asp.net MVC. and I used MVC template and it creates `.mdf` and `.ldf` file for database from my model automatically.

when I wanted to upload it on host, the host provider asked me to attach `.bak` file instead of the `.mdf` file which created automatically.

my question is that if my project will works fine with just converting the database to `.bak?` the way described in this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

and then my next question is that would my mvc web site works fine with `.bak` file insted of mdf?

Comment: A `.bak` (backup) file **cannot** be attached - it must be **restored** ....

Comment: @marc_s thank ypu so much so  I should attach `.mdf` file right? can you give me some more details?

Comment: You can create a SqlConnection on your app side to perform restore from your BAK file without creating MDF file first, by setting SqlCommand string like this: `new SqlCommand(String.Format("USE [master]; RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] FROM DISK='{0}' WITH REPLACE;", BakFilePath), connectionName);`, or use Restore operation if you have access to server's SSMS.

Comment: Yes, you must upload your .bak file for restoration. You must convert it to .bak file.

Comment: @DouglasThomas really thank you but i dont know ayn details of these is it possible to give me more details. or any link for tutorial?

Comment: Just check this tutorial https://forums.asp.net/p/1448416/3870094.aspx

Comment: @DouglasThomas thanks . if possible please answer and also a little explanation about why we should use `.bak` instead of `mdf.` .Appreciate

Comment: You cant use .mdf file on production server. .bak contains .mdf and .ldf file. If you only give .mdf, it will throw an error message. Please just ask it on forums.asp.net

Comment: thanks @DouglasThomas got it just if possible answer the question to accept then may help others. thanks again